# How can i get the session start username to echo out

Tags: php

Iam having issues echoing the session username and have no idea were to start any more cause every thing i have tried keeps saying string to array conversion but idk how to get this to correctly work. here is the code that would check for the loged in saying you logged in would you like to log out.

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])&& !empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "<P id='loged'>your loged in would you like to log out</p>";

    echo'<a href="logout.php">log out</a>';





}else{
    include 'logform.php';
}
```

Comment: did you do `echo $_SESSION['username'];` ?

Comment: try echo $_SESSION['username'] without any of these code
so if the session is actually set you can confirm

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `session_start()` before the $_SESSION variable will be available.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to echo the username?

```
echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['username];
```

Comment: and yes i want to echo the user name

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following answers your question...

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

...but you will also want to use session_start() first.

Also, no need to use isset() and !empty(), as empty() checks if it is set first. All you really need is:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['username']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention `session_start()` in the begining.

```
session_start(); //add this in the begining of the file.


echo $_SESSION['username'];  //this will display username
```

Comment: session start is in a another file that is included in cor.php and then this is what happens every time i echo the session Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\comments\index.php on line 18
Array

Comment: do `print_r($_SESSION)`.

Comment: it returns a key index array with a id of 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
call the function session_start() at beginning of the page and then check the $_SESSION array using

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);

after that you see all the indexes set in session variable.
```

- Thanks